# Show / Hide list items in Angular in the HTML

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have a list of 4 items, the first 2 visible and the last 2 hidden.

And a "show more / less" button that toggles the visibility of the last 2 items.

```
<ul>
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Item 2</li>
 <li class="hidden">Item 3</li>
 <li class="hidden">Item 4</li>
</ul>

<a href="#">Show More</a>
```

Is it possible to create this functionality in the HTML using Angular?

Do I need a component? Should I use a component?

Comment: In Angular the HTML is part of a component. So you need at least 1 component to have an Angular app.

Comment: Sure, I have already many components. What I was asking is if I need to have a variable in the component to make this work.

Comment: This is a very basic angular question. Suggest you to go through angular fundamentals, specifically [Components & Templates](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data) and you should be able to solve this easily.

Comment: yes, you'd need to bind it to a value. I'd say behavior like this may be more suited for a directive though; that way the scope of each would be more isolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <ul>
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Item 2</li>
 <li class="hidden" *ngIf ="hidden">Item 3</li>
 <li class="hidden" *ngIf ="hidden">Item 4</li>
 </ul>

<a href="#" (click)="toggle()">{{showMore}}</a>
```

Component:

```
export class AppComponent  {
showMore = 'show More'
hidden: boolean;
toggle(){
this.hidden = !this.hidden;
if(this.hidden){
 this.showMore = 'show less'
} 

if(!this.hidden){
 this.showMore = ' show more'
 }
 }
 }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fsppea?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Without component logic

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li class="hidden" *ngIf ="hidden">Item 3</li>
<li class="hidden" *ngIf ="hidden">Item 4</li>
</ul>

<a href="#" (click)="hidden = !hidden"> {{hidden ? 'show less' : 'show more'}}</a>
```

[Demo without component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fsppea?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Solutions:
(before all solutions you should add variable "visible" to your ts file)

1. Via removing elements from DOM:

> ```
> <ul>
>  <li>Item 1</li>
>  <li>Item 2</li>
>  <li *ngIf="visible">Item 3</li>
>  <li *ngIf="visible">Item 4</li>
> </ul>
> ```

2. Via dynamic class:
   html:

> ```
> <ul>
>  <li>Item 1</li>
>  <li>Item 2</li>
>  <li [class.some-hidden-class]="!visible">Item 3</li>
>  <li [class.some-hidden-class]="!visible">Item 4</li>
> </ul>
> ```

(s)css:

> ```
> .some-hidden-class{ display: none; }
> ```

3. Via hidden directive:

> ```
> <ul>
>      <li>Item 1</li>
>      <li>Item 2</li>
>      <li [hidden]="!visible">Item 3</li>
>      <li [hidden]="!visible">Item 4</li>
>     </ul>
> ```

In my opinion solution 1. is the best, because if elemenets are hidden then in DOM you don't see any inside HTML, so rendered HTML in 1th solution will look like:

```
<ul>
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

The biggest disadvantage of this solution is when some operation should doing when that elements is hidden (e.g you have some component inside and you want load required information before shown hidden elements, because all users will see that staf in near feature)

Solutions nr 2 and 3 is... the oposite of *ngIf (DOM contains HTML, so ts files allow do something with content, and also do some internal operation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NgIf directive to show and hide HTML items based on a condition.

[NgIf Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

```
<ul>
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Item 2</li>
 <li ngIf*="!hidden">Item 3</li>
 <li ngIf*="!hidden">Item 4</li>
</ul>

<a href="#">Show More</a>
```

"hidden" would be a variable (located in the typescript file) that can be toggled as either true/false. The li will be shown if hidden is false and hidden if hidden is true.